# Unable to create namespace quota using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, quota

I am facing the following issue related specifying namespace quota.

1. namespace quota specified is not getting created via helm.
   My file namspacequota.yaml is as shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: namespacequota
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "3"
    requests.memory: 10Gi
    limits.cpu: "6"
    limits.memory: 12Gi
```

Below command used for installation

```
helm install privachart3 . -n test-1
```

However the resourcequota is not getting created.

```
kubectl get resourcequota -n test-1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
NAME                  CREATED AT
gke-resource-quotas   2021-01-20T06:14:16Z
```

2. I can define the resource-quota using the below kubectl command.

`kubectl apply -f namespacequota.yaml --namespace=test-1`

The only change required in the file above is commenting of line number-5 that consist of release-name.

```
kubectl get resourcequota -n test-1
NAME                   CREATED AT
gke-resource-quotas    2021-01-20T06:14:16Z
namespacequota         2021-01-23T07:30:27Z
```

However in this case, when i am trying to install the chart, the PVC is created, but the POD is not getting created.

The capacity is not an issue as i am just trying to create a single maria-db pod using "Deployment".

Command used for install given below

```
helm install chart3 . -n test-1
```

Output observed given below

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
NAME: chart3
LAST DEPLOYED: Sat Jan 23 08:38:50 2021
NAMESPACE: test-1
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about your question. Is the quote resource not getting created or the pod is failing to get created?

Comment: 1. The quota is not getting created via the "helm install command".
2. When i create the qouta manually via "kubectl" command and then try to install the chart the pods dont get created,

Comment: did you place yaml file into templates folder?

Comment: Use `helm upgrade` with  `--debug` and observe what it shows.

Comment: @VasiliAngapov, yes i did miss that point and post making the correction my resourcequota is getting created with the "helm install command.

Comment: But issue remains with point number-2,  when resource-quota gets created for name-space, the pods dont get created... 

I helmfied a simple wordpress-appl from the link
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

If resource-quota gets created, then the PODs don't get created, there no issue with PVC or Service, but just the pods

If resource-quota section is removed then PODs get created

Comment: My code used can be downloaded from the below URL
https://github.com/helm/helm/files/5863957/chart-3.zip

Note: for creating secret being used by the application refer the below link
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/
I used the below command
kubectl create secret generic mysql-pass --from-literal=password=welcome1 -n <namespace-name>

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from another the Git forum.
Upon setting a namespace quota we need to explicitly set the POD's resource.
In my case i just needed to specify the resource limit under the image.

```
  - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

Post that i am now able to observe the PODs as well

```
[george@dis ]$ kubectl get resourcequota -n geo-test
NAME                  AGE   REQUEST                                                                                                                              LIMIT

gke-resource-quotas   31h   count/ingresses.extensions: 0/100, count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io: 0/100, count/jobs.batch: 0/5k, pods: 2/1500, services: 2/500   

namespace-quota       7s    requests.cpu: 500m/1, requests.memory: 128Mi/1Gi                                                                                     limits.cpu: 1/3, limits.memory: 256Mi/3Gi
[george@dis ]$ 
.



[george@dis ]$ kubectl get pod -n geo-test

NAME                                 READY     STATUS     RESTARTS     AGE

wordpress-7687695f98-w7m5b           1/1       Running     0           32s

wordpress-mysql-7ff55f869d-2w6zs     1/1       Running     0           32s

[george@dis ]$
```